# Getting an int from List<Node> method

Tags: java, arrays, controller, artificial-intelligence, pacman

I am new to Java programming and have a problem. For this project we are doing, a pac man AI controller, we are given a method `List(Node) getPillNodes()` (same for powerpills as well) which returns all the indices that have pills throughout the maze. What I am trying to do is to tell pac man to go after those pills by checking which pills are available still on the maze, however I am unsure how to work with that method. My only idea was to use an `int[]` and do some array math for checking. Is there a way to get that to work? Or a better idea?

Comment: I think you're going to need to clarify what exactly you need help with. This isn't very clear.

Comment: Sorry, as I said, I am very new to this, so it is hard for me to explain. What I am trying to do is tell pacman to go in a certain direction, I need to return where the pills are, which is given to use in the method I described above ,  and then do something like this                                            int[] pills=game.getPillNodes();
  int[] powerPills=game.getPowerPillIndices();  
  
  ArrayList<Integer> targets=new ArrayList<Integer>();
  
  for(int i=0;i<pills.length;i++)   //check which pills are available   
   if(game.checkPill(i))
    targets.add(pills[i]);

Comment: However, I don't know how to get from a List(Node) to be able to use that in an Int[], since they are not the same types. If there is a better way to do this than what I'm trying, please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: Show us your code!!